# Generate KeyPair using Public and Private JKS files

Tags: java, keystore, key-pair

Is it possible to generate a `KeyPair` for use within my application using already generated Public and Private keystore (JKS) files?

Thanks

```
KeyPairGenerator keyGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
keyGen.initialize(2048);
KeyPair keypair = keyGen.genKeyPair();
```

I want to create key pair with already generated `RSA 2048` private and public key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use like below:

```
public static KeyPair loadKeyStore(final File keystoreFile,
        final String password, final String alias, final String keyStoreType)
        throws Exception {
    if (null == keystoreFile) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Keystore url may not be null");
    }
    final KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance(keyStoreType);
    InputStream is = null;
    try {
        is = new FileInputStream(keystoreFile);
        keystore.load(is, null == password ? null : password.toCharArray());
    } finally {
        if (null != is) {
            is.close();
        }
    }
    final PrivateKey key = (PrivateKey) keystore.getKey(alias,
            password.toCharArray());
    final Certificate cert = keystore.getCertificate(alias);
    final PublicKey publicKey = cert.getPublicKey();
    return new KeyPair(publicKey, key);

}
```

Comment: For the parameter "final File keystoreFile" do we pass the public or private keystore?

Comment: When i load the private keystore I get an exception for this code `Exception in thread "main" java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Cannot recover key`

Comment: Ah issue is both cert and key have different password so I need to pass both key and cert pass. I've updated the code slightly and it works